# How to upload file using multer or body-parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, body-parser

I am a NodeJS beginner, following along a book "Web Development with MongoDB and NodeJS". I am stuck at its chapter 6 with 'multer'. When I use multer for file uploads the server throws the following error:

```
/Users/fk / Documents / imageuploader / node_modules / express / lib / application.js: 209
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions'); ^

TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
```

but when I replace it with bodyParser the server fires up but when I click the upload button it gives me the following error on the browser.

```
500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
```

However, it is supposed to redirect me towards another page, where the uploaded file is shown.

Here is my bodyParser code, please see if I am using it correctly because it gives me "body-parser deprecated" at the starting of the server. I've seen other questions like mine and I followed but none of them really work.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser({
  uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, '../public/upload/temp')
}));
```

Following code shows how I use multer, just in case if there is something I shouldn't be doing please let me know. Which one would be better in case of uploading files, body-parser or multer?

```
app.use(multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, '../public/upload/temp')
}));


var saveImage = function() {
  var possible = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
    imgUrl = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    imgUrl += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  var tempPath = req.files.file.path,
    ext = path.extname(req.files.file.name).toLowerCase(),
    targetPath = path.resolve('./public/upload/' + imgUrl + ext);

  if (ext === '.png' || ext === '.jpg' || ext === '.jpeg' || ext === '.gif') {
    fs.rename(tempPath, targetPath, function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.redirect('/images/' + imgUrl);
    });
  } else {
    fs.unlink(tempPath, function() {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.json(500, {
        error: 'Only image files are allowed.'
      });
    });
  }
};
saveImage();
```

Preceding block of code is the logic that I am using to upload the file. In the error it is referring to 'file' as undefined which is in the following line in the saveImage function. It is unable to get the path and therefore throws error 500 according to the else part of the saveImage function. Why is 'file' undefined here? I dont get it.

```
var tempPath = req.files.file.path,
```

Comment: I am following http://wiki.workassis.com/nodejs-express-get-post-multipart-request-handling-example/ this example

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`multer()` returns a middleware generator that uses the settings you specified, so you cannot pass its return value directly to `app.use()`. You can see all of the types of middleware it can generate in the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), but typically the generated middleware are added at the route level instead of globally like the other body parsers. This is because you will typically pass in the name of the file field(s) that you will be expecting.

For example, this will accept a single file (along with any non-file fields) whose form field name is `foo`:

```
var upload = multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, '../public/upload/temp')
});

// ...

app.post('/upload', upload.single('foo'), function(req, res) {
  if (req.file) {
    console.dir(req.file);
    return res.end('Thank you for the file');
  }
  res.end('Missing file');
});
```

Also, `body-parser` does not currently export a `multipart/form-data`-capable middleware, so you cannot use that module for handling uploaded files (well, short of passing a base64-encoded string in an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form or something, but that's much less efficient).

Answer (score 10):

Here is the basic code for file upload in MEAN please check

HTML

```
<form id="frmDoc" name="frmDocument" ng-submit="upload()" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_email">Document<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="file" name="file" id='file' required="required" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group form-actions">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

---

CLIENT SIDE CODE

```
app.controller ('myctrl',function($scope,$http){

  $scope.upload = function () {
            var file = angular.element(document.querySelector('#file')).prop("files")[0];
                $scope.files = [];
                $scope.files.push(file);
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/users/upload',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                    transformRequest: function (data) {
                        var formData = new FormData();
                        formData.append('model', angular.toJson(data.model));
                        formData.append('file', data.files[0]);
                        return formData;
                    },
                    data: { model: { title: 'hello'}, files: $scope.files }

                }).success(function (res) {
                    console.log(res)
                });
        }


});
```

---

SERVER SIDE CODE

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    //var code = JSON.parse(req.body.model).empCode;
    var dest = 'public/uploads/';
    mkdirp(dest, function (err) {
        if (err) cb(err, dest);
        else cb(null, dest);
    });
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

router.post('/upload', upload.any(), function(req , res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.files);
});
```

Comment: Hi what if i want to send multiple files what changes do i need to make on my angular transformRequest function which is inside $http function

Comment: loop through all your fileInput and append each file on formData like this.
for( let i=0 ; i<filesToUpload.length ; i++){  
  let file = filesToUpload[i];
formData.append("file", file);
}

Comment: I am trying to upload my image from postman using your code. but file is not saving in upload directory. Any help ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the code of the book "Web Development with MongoDB and NodeJS" as follows:

```
app.use(multer({dest:path.join(__dirname,'../public/upload/temp')}).any());
.
.
.
.
const tempPath = req.files[0].path,  // Temporary location of uploaded file
ext = path.extname(req.files[0].originalname).toLowerCase(), // Get file extension of the uploaded file
targetPath = path.resolve(`./public/upload/${imgUrl}${ ext}`); // The final path for the image file
```

The other parts of code remained intact. It worked and I could upload image files.
Best wishes,
Mehrdad Sheikhan

Answer (score -1):

**Code for upload file using Multer and save it to local folder**

```
api- call fileUpload function
fileUpload(req)
    .then(uploadRes => {
        console.log('uploadRes', uploadRes)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err)
    })


Create file upload service
const multer = require('multer') // import library
const moment = require('moment')
const q = require('q')
const _ = require('underscore')
const fs = require('fs')
let dir = './public'

/** Store file on local folder */
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, dir)
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        let date = moment(moment.now()).format('YYYYMMDDHHMMSS')
        cb(null, date + '_' + file.originalname.replace(/-/g, '_').replace(/ /g, '_'))
    }
})

/** Upload files */
let upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array('files')

/** Exports fileUpload function */
module.exports = {
    fileUpload: function (req) {
        let deferred = q.defer()

        /** Create dir if not exist */
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir)
            console.log(`\n\n ${dir} dose not exist, hence created \n\n`)
        }

        upload(req, {}, function (err) {
            if (req && (_.isEmpty(req.files))) {
                deferred.resolve({ status: 200, message: 'File not attached', data: [] })
            } else {
                if (err) {
                    deferred.reject({ status: 400, message: 'error', data: err })
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve({
                        status: 200,
                        message: 'File attached',
                        filename: _.pluck(req.files,
                            'filename'),
                        data: req.files
                    })
                }
            }
        })
        return deferred.promise
    }
}
```