# Postman response body empty on using 'form-data'

Tags: node.js, rest, postman, body-parser

I started working on my new node API after some time and all of sudden, data testing using Postman 'form-data' stopped working. Data is getting stored into the database with status code 200 but the request body (title and category) shows empty. I tried using the raw body and works perfect but need to use form-data to send files in the body as well.

Here is my **app.js** snippet:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, application/json, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, PATCH');
        return res.status(200).json();
    }
    next();
});

app.use('/articles', articleRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});
```

**model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: String,
    category: String,
    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('article', articleSchema);
```

**Articleroute.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const articleController = require('../controllers/articles');
router.get('/', articleController.article_get_all);
router.post('/', articleController.article_create);
module.exports = router;
```

**article_create**

```
exports.article_create = (req, res, next) => {

    const body = req.body;

    body._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

    const article = new Article(body);
    article
        .save()
        .then(docs => {
            console.log(docs, 'article');
            res.status(200).json(docs);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
};
```

I tried reinstalling body-parser module but all in vain.

[postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwBqx.jpg)

Here is the postman result of using form-data:

```
{
    "_id": "5c76d1c01c20fa064cbcbaf1",
    "date": "2019-02-27T18:06:56.287Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Posted node code only handles CORS.

Comment: Add more details on which requests are you trying to do with which params. Try to add handlers which supposed to handle these requests.

Comment: @extempl I have updated the question with my model and route in the app.js

Comment: I don't see any part of sending multipart/form-data

Comment: `articleRoutes` code? Example of request you trying to send via postman?

Comment: @CharlieH I was following the same approach some times back without multipart/form-data and it was working. But now it is not. I even tried setting form-data into header

Comment: @extempl please check the edited part now

Comment: Looks like `articleController.article_get_all` is not sending multipart/form-data for some reason.

Comment: @CharlieH that's what even I am not able to figure out. It seemed to be working fine before.

Comment: Also the postman screenshot shown an unsuccessful request.

Comment: Yup, it looks like your post handler expects json in body, and you sending form-data instead, so it responds to you about parse issue.

Comment: @extempl raw body is working fine, so is form-data but form-data is showing empty data body with the only date created a default. Also, I am converting data using JSON while posting in controller

Comment: @extempl Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Nvm, I misunderstood the issue and noticed that you updated your screenshot to a successful one. so removed that comment.

Comment: Can you share also `article_create` (is it just creating a model?), or, maybe, full minimum working example (w/o db, just logging the received data)?

Comment: @extempl updated. It is not only creating an empty model. Data is getting POSTed but empty body

Comment: Btw, from bodyParser page https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser - it says that it providing `URL-encoded form body parser`. 
Therefore, have you tried to add `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));` and use `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead?

Comment: What is the content-type of the response?

Comment: @extempl Yes, extended has been set to true already and it is working for x-www-form-urlencoded. But I will also be needed to send the file using postman. So neither of the raw format or x-www-form-urlencoded will handle that file uploading.

Comment: @CharlieH Its json only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36203101/506954

Comment: This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

busboy and connect-busboy
multiparty and connect-multiparty
formidable
multer

Comment: @extempl Thanks a lot. Will try this. Might help out

Comment: ^ That's from the package readme, so there are no any chances to get file via `body-parser`.